# Error in raster histogram in QGIS3.0 with PyQGIS

Tags: raster, pyqgis, histogram

I am working on a plugin, one of its functions is to create the raster layer histogram.
I generate the histogram using the histogram method of QgsRasterInterface and graph it well, without problems in QGis3.4.
But in QGis3.0 it does not allow to generate the histogram.
This is a recognized error? when creating the histogram in QGis3.0?

```
capa=iface.activeLayer()
provider=capa.dataProvider()
provider.initHistogram(QgsRasterHistogram(), 1, 20)
histogram = provider.histogram(1,20) 
y=histogram.histogramVector
```

Details:

- If I get correctly the statistics with bandStatistics
- The values of histogram.minimum and histogram.maximum do not coincide with the maximum and minimum of the statistics.
- Try assigning the maximum, minimum and extension parameters. As well as placing None,None, but I still did not get a result
- I try to create the histogram without initializing it or defining no data, could this be the error in QGIS3.0?

Comment: Of course, Of course, for example this code:

Comment: In QGIS3.0 histogram.maximum and histogram.minimum give incorrect values. The histogramVector is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in binCount (the length of **histogramVector**) assigning for histogram object. It is enough with band value in:

```
.
.
.
histogram = provider.histogram(1)
.
.
.
```

where 1 is number band. So, by using a test raster with 20x20 values between 1 and 20, following code ran in Python Console it will produce:

```
>>>layer = iface.activeLayer()
>>>provider = layer.dataProvider()
>>>provider.initHistogram(QgsRasterHistogram(), 0, 20) #using binCount = 20
>>>histogram = provider.histogram(1)
>>>print(histogram.minimum, histogram.maximum)
1.0 20.0  #result as expected
>>>print(histogram.histogramVector)
[14, 20, 28, 25, 26, 22, 16, 14, 23, 21, 20, 21, 17, 16, 23, 18, 14, 14, 25, 23]
```

Resulting last line is indicating that the raster has 14 values for 1 value, 20 values for 2 value, 28 values for 3 value, ..., 23 values for pixels with 20 value.

Sum of **histogram.histogramVector**:

14, 20, 28, 25, 26, 22, 16, 14, 23, 21, 20, 21, 17, 16, 23, 18, 14, 14, 25, 23

is 400 (20 x 20) as expected. It worked for me.

Comment: Xunilk thanks for your answer, I'm going to try varying the amount of bins and I'll tell you